# H2 - Create index on linked table and perform JOIN on linked tables

Tags: java, h2

I have a MySQL tables `tableName` and `table2` with indices defined on it.

I created in my Java application a linked table `tableName` with this query:

`CREATE LINKED TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName('', 'jdbc:mysql://hostName:port/dbName', 'user', 'pass', 'tableName');`

The same query for `table2`.

Then I created `tableSelect` in H2 database with the query:

`CREATE TABLE tableSelect AS SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Sex = 'F'`

Now my Java application create an index if not exist on `table2` with this query:

`CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS DES ON table2(DES);`

and it gives me an error like this when I click a button to re-run query:
`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "LINK"; SQL statement:`

Furthermore if indicices are defined I perform a `JOIN` on indices already defined, but it is too slow. The query JOIN involve a table in H2 and a table in MySQL, that is the linked table and it is like this:

`CREATE TABLE tableNew AS SELECT l.*, CONTR AS Activity FROM t AS ableSelect JOIN table2 AS agg ON l.Contr_Type = agg.DES;`

How can I optimize this JOIN?

Comment: H2 <> MySQL. What exactly are you using ?

Comment: I'm using H2. In MySQL there are tables that I linked in H2

Comment: Let mysql do the query

Comment: I can't do that because I have a table in H2 database and a table in MySQL defined as linked table in H2 database

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an index on linked table in H2 for oblivious reasons. But you can create such index in MySQL and it will be used. However, it you need to join many rows you query will work very slow anyway.

You can create an additional temporary copy of the table from MySQL in H2 with `CREATE TABLE newName AS SELECT … FROM linkedTable`, create all necessary indexes in that copy, and use it in your `JOIN` instead of the linked table. Of course, this copy will not reflect changes performed in the MySQL database.

If **both** sides of the `JOIN` are linked tables, you can create a linked table with a query and work with it.

```sql
CREATE LINKED TABLE tableName('', 'jdbc:…', 'user', 'password', '(SELECT … FROM … JOIN … ON …)');
```

Such query will be executed by the MySQL and it should be relatively fast.

Comment: I can't perform ```JOIN``` on MySQL because I have a table ```tableSelect``` in H2 database and ```table2``` as linked table.

Comment: In that case create a copy of the linked table, add indexes to it, and use this copy instead of the linked table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I explain the problem better. I have ```tableSelect``` in H2 database, ```table2``` in MySQL and I want to create a new table ```tableNew``` in H2 as a result from ```JOIN``` of these two tables. What should I do to do that JOIN in a efficient manner?

Comment: 1. `CREATE TABLE copy AS SELECT * FROM table2`. 2. `CREATE INDEX indexName ON copy(columnName)`. 3. Rewrite your query with `copy` instead of `table2`. 4. Drop the `copy` if it isn't needed any more.

Comment: How 1. works on H2 database if ```table2``` is in MySQL? These ```copy``` table will create on H2?

Comment: I assume that `table2` is the name of the linked table that you created. Anyway, you need to create a linked table under some name and a copy of that table under another name (with `CREATE TABLE nameOfTheCopy AS SELECT column1, … FROM nameOfTheLinkedTable`). You will be able to add indexes to that copy and use it in your query. Such copy will be faster than the linked table.

Comment: okay! It works Now the JOIN operations took a fewer seconds!! If you converted the last comment in answer I can accept this as a solution.

Comment: Can you tell me why only this query is running slowly? I use the same operations you descibed previously. ```CREATE TABLE filter1 AS SELECT log.*, m.ACT FROM temp AS log JOIN (SELECT p.DES_PROV AS ACT, c.DES_COM AS com FROM tableState AS c JOIN tableProv AS p ON c.COD_PROV = p.COD_PROV) AS m ON log.Place = m.com ORDER BY Cod```

Comment: The last comment is not very different from the main answer. If you have a slow query with only own tables of H2 you can use `EXPLAIN SELECT …` to check the execution plan of the query. Usually you need indexes on columns that are used in `ON` condition of joins.

Comment: I've defined ```log.Place``` as index, but how can I define ```m.com``` as index as ```m``` is a table defined within query?

Comment: Index on one side could be enough for inner join. Also it looks like you can rewrite your query without a subquery to improve performance. I think you should post this query as a separate question and include the output of `EXPLAIN` in that question.